# How to Auto Increment ID Numbers with Letters and Numbers MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, primary-key

I am trying to set up a table in MS Acess with Primary Key which would consist of letter and numbers and would auto increment.
Can anyone help me with it?

> Example of ID Column:
>   B0114
>   B0214
>   ...
>   B0914
>   B1014

B <- my chosen letter for this table
Number in the middle is the auto increment one
14 - year, as per 2014, might be a constant

Comment: What happens at `B9914`?

Comment: You can't autoincrement mixed types. Either manually increment them, or separate them into two separate fields, auto-increment the number, and then increment the letter as needed from code. You can format them however you like for presentation to the user.